# Выделение активной ссылки при переходе по ссылке

Tags: javascript, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
.header-menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}

.header-menu ul li a.active {
      color: #c58a52;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header-menu">
                    <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">сервисы</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">портфолио</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">профиль</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">блог</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
       </nav>
```

Если здесь запустить код, то выделение работает, но на сайте при переходе по ссылке/обновлении стиль сбрасывается. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Вы страницу перезагружаете?

Comment: да, конечно. в href реальные ссылки на страницы, ну или просто при обновлении стиль .active сбрасывается, я понимаю, что причина в этом. Но как оставить подсвечивание при переходе/обновлении?

Comment: Как вариант, можно распарсить `url` и поискать по атрибуту `href` совпадения. Если такое есть дописать класс `active`.

Comment: Нужно что-то добавить в существующий JS код?

Comment: Конечно. Хотя-бы парсинг урл.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location